# Permanent Transparent Block in a Frame in Beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays, transparency

In a frame I have two blocks: the first is visible, while the second should be transparent.

With

```
\frame{
\frametitle{title}
\begin{block}{title visible block}
\end{block}
\invisible{\begin{block}{title invisible block}
\end{block}}
}
```

The first block is visible and the second one invisible. I would like to make the second block transparent rather than invisible.
How can I do this?

EDIT:

This is partially the code of 3 slides.

```
\frame{
\frametitle{title}
\begin{block}<1->{procedure-1}
 \begin{center}
   \includegraphics[height=1.3in,width=4in]{images/procedure-1.png}
 \end{center}
\end{block}
\invisible{\begin{block}{Mathematical Formulation}
\begin{equation}
 0+0=0
\end{equation}
\end{block}}
}
\frame{
\frametitle{title}
\begin{block}<1->{procedure-2}
 \begin{center}
   \includegraphics[height=1.3in,width=4in]{images/procedure-2.png}
 \end{center}
\end{block}
\invisible{\begin{block}{Mathematical Formulation}
\begin{equation}
 0+0=0
\end{equation}
\end{block}}
}
\frame{
\frametitle{title}
\begin{block}<1->{procedure-3}
 \begin{center}
   \includegraphics[height=1.3in,width=4in]{images/procedure-3.png}
 \end{center}
\end{block}
\begin{block}<2->{Mathematical Formulation}
\begin{equation}
 0+0=0
\end{equation}
\end{block}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting the manual:

> `\invisible<⟨overlay specification⟩>{⟨text⟩}`
>
> This command is the opposite of `\visible`.

So, what does `\visible` do? Quoting again the manual:

> `\visible<⟨overlay specification⟩>{⟨text⟩}`
>
> This command does almost the same as `\uncover`. The only difference is that if the text is not shown, it is never shown in a transparent way, but rather it is not shown at all. Thus, for this command the transparency settings have no effect.

Therefore, if you really want to have the second block transparent, you *don't have* to use `\invisible`.

You can use `\onslide` for example, of course by specifying first `\setbeamercovered{transparent}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mwe}% for dummy images
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\only<1>{
\begin{block}{procedure-1}
 \centering% use this and not the center environment
 \includegraphics<1>[height=1.3in,width=4in]{example-image}
\end{block}
}
\only<2>{
\begin{block}{procedure-2}
 \centering% use this and not the center environment
 \includegraphics<2>[height=1.3in,width=4in]{example-image-a}
\end{block}
}
\only<3->{
\begin{block}{procedure-3}
 \centering% use this and not the center environment
 \includegraphics<3->[height=1.3in,width=4in]{example-image-c}
\end{block}
}
\onslide<4>{
\begin{block}{Mathematical Formulation}
\begin{equation}
 0+0=0
\end{equation}
\end{block}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: I need the second block must be transparent all the time. It must not appear after a click.

Comment: May I ask you what is the purpose? If something should not appear, probably it is convenient to show it at all, rather than half visible and you save space.

Comment: I edited my initial question. ;)

Comment: I've seen the edit: the problem is that you can achieve your purpose with overlays rather than having 3 separates frames. I'll edit my answer in this sense.

Comment: Grazie Claudio. ;)

Comment: @no_name: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with

```
\setbeamercovered{transparent}  
\frame<1>{
  \frametitle{title} 
  \onslide<1->{Some text} 
  \onslide<2->{Transparent text}
    \begin{block}{title visible block} 
}
```

The <1> after frame will make the slide continue after the time of 1