# Make an \item (or block) permanently transparent on all frames/subframes

Tags: beamer, itemize, transparency, only

I believe this question has been asked two other times, but there have not been any satisfying answers.

1. [Permanent Transparent Block in a Frame in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123382/permanent-transparent-block-in-a-frame-in-beamer?rq=1)
2. [Permanent transparent block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153406/permanent-transparent-block?rq=1)

I think previous answers didn't quite understand the purpose of such a thing, so I'll lay out my particular example and reasoning. I have a to-do list for two projects. I want to

- show the to-do list on frame 1, highlighting only the first project
- tangent on frames 2 and 3, touching on parts of the first project
- show the to-do list again on frame 4, highlighting only the second project
- tangent on frame 5, touching on parts of the second project

The basic code should look something like this:

```
% FRAME 1
\begin{frame}{To Do} \setbeamercovered{transparent=30}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1->[1)] Project 1
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<1,2>[\checkmark] A
    \item<1,3>[x] B
    \item<1,3>[x] C
    \end{itemize}
\item[2)] Project 2       % I want this to have 30% opacity
    \begin{itemize}       % I want this to have 30% opacity
    \item[\checkmark] D   % I want this to have 30% opacity
    \item[\checkmark] E   % I want this to have 30% opacity
    \item[x] F            % I want this to have 30% opacity
    \end{itemize}         % I want this to have 30% opacity
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

% FRAME 2 
\begin{frame}{Project 1: Item B}
\lipsum[1] % Explaining what to do for item B
\end{frame}

% FRAME 3 
\begin{frame}{Project 1: Item C}
\lipsum[2] % Explaining what to do for item C
\end{frame}

% FRAME 4
\begin{frame}{To Do} \setbeamercovered{transparent=30}
\begin{itemize}
\item[1)] Project 1       % I want this to have 30% opacity
    \begin{itemize}       % I want this to have 30% opacity
    \item[\checkmark] A   % I want this to have 30% opacity
    \item[x] B            % I want this to have 30% opacity
    \item[x] C            % I want this to have 30% opacity
    \end{itemize}         % I want this to have 30% opacity
\item<1->[2)] Project 2       
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<1,2>[\checkmark] D
    \item<1,2>[\checkmark] E
    \item<1,3>[x] F
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

% FRAME 5 
\begin{frame}{Project 2: Item F}
\lipsum[2] % Explaining what to do for item f
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Please add a compilable minimal working example including all packages etc. necessary to compile your code

Comment: Why aren't the previous answers satisfying?  Do they not work?

Answer (score -1):

I have found a partial solution to get the desired effect. But there are issues. While I don't accept my own solution as a *best answer*, I'll post it on the off chance nothing better is available.

If you add `\includepackage{transparent}` to your preamble, you can use `{\transparent{30} <stuff>}` to get 30% opacity. The caveats:

- Sparing the details, it does not work in some specific cases if you are using `\item<>`.
- It does, however, work if you are using `\pause`. That being said, if the `\transparent` block comes *after* the pause, it will have two layers of transparency.

So I propose a poor solution, which is achieved by breaking the itemize environment into two parts and manually fudging the spacing.

```
% FRAME 1
\begin{frame}{To Do} \setbeamercovered{transparent=30}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1->[1)] Project 1
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<1,2>[\checkmark] A
    \item<1,3>[x] B
    \item<1,3>[x] C
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\vspace*{1em}           %Fudge manual spacing
{\transparent{0.3}      %Start of 30% opacity
\begin{itemize}
\item[2)] Project 2
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[\checkmark] D
    \item[\checkmark] E
    \item[x] F
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
}                        %End of 30% opacity
\end{frame}


% FRAME 4
\begin{frame}{To Do} \setbeamercovered{transparent=30}
{\transparent{0.3}     %Start of 30% opacity
\begin{itemize}
\item[1)] Project 1
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[\checkmark] A
    \item[x] B
    \item[x] C
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\vspace*{1em}           %Fudge manual spacing
}                       %End of 30% opacity
\begin{itemize}
\item<1->[2)] Project 2 \pause
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<1,2>[\checkmark] D
    \item<1,2>[\checkmark] E \pause
    \item<1,3>[x] F
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```